# What would happen if there were two Collectives?

Tags: star-trek, borg

Consider this: An instance occurs where two Borg Collectives are formed. I'm not asking how that would happen, I'm asking WHAT would happen. The two groups are the same in practically every way, but they were somehow programmed to be enemies. Would one eventually assimilate the other, and become one? Would they simply fight until there's nothing left? Thank you for your time.

Comment: A new addition to the Shark vs. Gorilla trope: Shark vs. Shark.

Comment: @Praxis - Well, it would be if we hadn't seen almost that exact occurrence in Voyager

Comment: This also happened in a [TNG episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Descent_%28episode%29).

Comment: "Let's get ready to RUUUUMMMMBLEEEE!!!!!!!"

Comment: This actually happens in STO, there is the normal borg collective, and then a separate collective of essentially free'd borg.

Answer (score 2):

We see this happen in the episode [VOY: Unity](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/312.htm). A small number of Borg are disconnected from the collective and eventually (after 42 minutes, coincidentally) manage to reconfigure theirselves to form a non-Borg "co-operative".

Their immediate fear is that the presence of a Borg cube will attract the attention of the Borg Collective and, given their known predilection for attempting to assimilate anything that is novel or useful, I think we can be pretty certain that they would attack if they knew about them.

So the answer to your question is a solid **yes**. If the Borg Collective encountered another non-Borg Borg Collective, they would likely make stern efforts to assimilate each other.

Comment: Not necessarily.  There is a big difference between a few units and trillions+ of them.  Againts a few units, it is safe to assume that the full Collective will quickly override them but against another full collective worth trillions of units; a mutual destruction can be predicted and in this case, we don't know what they will do: going into a full war or safely remains out of reach of each other?  Honestly, this question is totally hypothetical.

Comment: @SylvainL - If they were actually equal there would be no need for a conflict. They would simply determine which was in the tactically superior position and merge their consciousnesses under a single unified leadership. Note that it's only individual Borg that are controlled by programming, their ultimate leadership is controlled by a highly-intelligent entity.

Comment: saying that the Borg collective is controlled by some independant entity (or entities) having total free will and absolute control over all of his decisions is totally hypothetical.  We know nothing about its leadership. We have seen some queens in action but while they were taking decisions, it was always in order to pursue some assigned missions on behalf of the Collective.  From what we know, it's impossible to say if the Collective can make the decision to go to war or not.

Comment: @SylvainL - I don't disagree. All of the Collective's members (including the Queen) serve the will of the Collective. That will *seems* to be a gestalt consciousness with a singular aim.